# SiteMap control based on user roles doesn't works

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, roles, role-based

```
  <siteMapNode roles="*">

    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title=" Main" description="Main" roles="*"/>

    <siteMapNode url="~/Items.aspx" title=" Adv" description="Adv" roles="Administrator"/>

....
```

**any user can see Adv page.** That is a trouble and a qustion : why and how to hide out of role sitenodes.

but if I do `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator")` it shows me if user in Administrator role or not.

web config :

```
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="FlowWebSQL" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="/" name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="FlowWebSQL" name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) tag in web.config.

```
<location path ="Items.aspx" >

   <system.web>

     <authorization>

       <allow roles ="Administrator"/>
       <deny users="*"/>
     </authorization>

   </system.web>

 </location>
```

See following for step by step custom role implementation
http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-role-provider-sitemap-navigation.html

Comment: hm... looking like I can not use System.Web into App_Code of WebApplication.

Comment: also... I have no different folders for each role.
If I do folders some folders must be able for some roles (not one role - one folder)

Answer (score 2):

Enable security trimming
Security trimming is not enabled by default, and it cannot be enabled programmatically; it can only be set in the Web.config file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

Comment: aha... problem is here :

  <siteMapNode roles="*">
    
    <siteMapNode url="~  // Role appears to all internal nodes

Comment: Site map datasource request only one element